# Среднее арифметическое из массива классов

Tags: javascript, массивы, классы, объекты

Помогите пожалуйста вывести среднее арифметическое из массива,при помощи функции которая принимает массив. Моя функция выдает NaN!!! Почему?

```
    class Car{
    constructor(prise){  
        this.prise = prise;
    }
};
function averageСost(arr) {
        var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    total = (total + arr[i]) / arr.length;;
}
 return total;
    } ;

var car1 = new Car(10000);
var car2 = new Car(20000);
var car3 = new Car (30000);
var cars = [car1,car2,car3];  

console.log(averageСost(cars));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function averageСost(arr) {
   var sum = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       sum += arr[i];
   }
   return sum / arr.length;
}

console.log(averageСost([3, 6, 2, 9]));
```

А также, можно написать все это за одну строчку используя функцию [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
function averageСost(arr) {
   return arr.reduce((partial_sum, a) => partial_sum + a, 0) / arr.length; 
}

console.log(averageСost([3, 6, 2, 9]));
```